# Split a HTML document at tag - Python

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

What would be the best way to split a HTML document/string based on the occurrence of the 
 tag? I have given the solution I currently have below but it seems quite cumbersome and isn't all that easy to read I think. I also experimented with regex's but I'm told I should not use regex's to parse HTML

```
for i, br in enumerate(soup.findAll('b')):
line_value = ''
line_values = []
next = br.next
while (next):
    if next and isinstance(next, Tag) and next.name == 'br':
        line_values.append(line_value)
        line_value = ''
    else:
        stripped_text = ''.join(BeautifulSoup(str(next).strip()).findAll(text=True))
        if stripped_text:
            line_value += stripped_text
    next = next.nextSibling
print line_values
```

Here's a sample of the HTML I'm parsing:

```
<p><font size="1" color="#800000"><b>09:00
  <font> - </font>
  11:00
  <br>
  CE4817
  <font> - </font>LAB <font>- </font>
  2A
  <br>
   B2043 B2042
  <br>

  Wks:1-13
  </b></font>
  </p>
```

And the current results of my code:

```
[u'09:00 - 11:00', u'CE4817 - LAB- 2A', u'B2043 B2042']
[u'11:00 - 12:00', u'CE4607 - TUT- 3A', u'A1054']
```

Comment: I'm asking a clarification: do you need to split the html document given a tag or just remove all tags from the input?

Comment: I need to split on the occurence of the br tag (or another specified tag)

Answer (score 0):

To split with regexes

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'<br>')
filter(None, p.split(yourString))
```

Then you can remove the other html tags from each of the returned strings in the array.

You can either use an existing function, as in [Strip html from strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925630/876211) 
or check my answer to the question [Stripping HTML tags without using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990111/876211).

Check also this answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/876211)

You should *really* use an html parser to accomplish your task

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Regex**

```
<p><font size="1" color="#800000"><b>(\d{2}:\d{2}).*?(\d{2}:\d{2}).*?(\w{2}\d{4}).*?<font> - </font>(\w+)\s*<font>- </font>\s*(\d\w)\s*<br>\s*(\w\d{4}\s*\w\d{4})\s*<br>[\s\S]*?</p>
```

**Mode**

> m - multiline

This will work as long as the structure of the html code doesn't change.